# Java Spring style: factory for a category of processor for a given class

Tags: java, spring

I have a trivial question about spring style.

Given a set of Java classes:

ClassA, ClassB, ClassC & ClassD.

These classes are from another system and cannot be changed.

These classes have to processed by a different processor. Some of the classes are processed by common processors.

So my question is what is the best spring way to map the classes onto their processors. Currently I've got a factory bean with does something like this:

```
package org.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class processorFactory
{

private static List<Object> proc1List = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(
        classA.class, classB.class));

private static List<Object> proc2List = new ArrayList<Object>(
        Arrays.asList(classC.class));

private static List<Object> proc3List = new ArrayList<Object>(
        Arrays.asList(classD.class));

public static processor getProcessor(Object object)
{

    if (proc1List.contains(object))
        return new processor1();
    else if (proc2List.contains(object))
        return new processor2();
    else if (proc3List.contains(object))
        return new processor3();

    throw new RuntimeException("no processor.");
}
}
```

Most of the code is redundant with spring. I'm sure there are various ways to do it, but my question is what is the best way to implement this in spring with annotations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Java Config, then you could convert your code above directly.  That is, your "factory" code would become the @Bean code for creation of a Processor (which should have a capital "P" :)

Comment: Yes that's more or less what I've got in the real code. It has the the capital P too :-). But I was wondering if there is a better way to do it -  Spring is supposed to be a sophisticated object factory so it might have support for a better approach.